# GIT: do not want ANY changes to be auto-merged, even the most obvious ones

Tags: git-merge

I'm a new GIT user who has been experimenting with what happens when you do a PULL and differences are found between two versions of a file when I do a PULL.

From what I have seen, if two changes do not conflict with each other (e.g. one is at the top of a file and one is at the bottom of a file), the diffs will be resolved AUTOMATICALLY, w/o any intervention on my part. OTOH, if they are, for example, at the same line of code, I am asked to resolve them manually via the KDIFF3 editor.

The way we work at my company, we do not want GIT/KDIFF3 to do ANY merging automatically. In other words, I want the same dialog that comes up when GIT CANNOT resolve changes to come up for ALL changes, even the most obvious.

Is there a setting, option, or something else that can let me do this within the same flow of control? (PS-I've tried the option where you just do a fetch but I can't figure out what's going on with that and would rather avoid it anyhow.)

Many thanks.
-Steve

Comment: Are you just looking for git pull --no-commit?

Answer (score 0):

Use git fetch, it won't do any merging. Check out this link to see the difference between pull and fetch. http://blog.mikepearce.net/2010/05/18/the-difference-between-git-pull-git-fetch-and-git-clone-and-git-rebase/

EDIT: Just read the last part of your post. I don't know of any way to do a pull without a merge, as that what it is designed to do. I believe fetch is your only option if you want to avoid merging.

EDIT2: I haven't tried this personally, but the following blog post has an approach that seems to fit what you are asking for: http://jasonrudolph.com/blog/2009/02/25/git-tip-how-to-merge-specific-files-from-another-branch/

For your case, what I believe you would do is after performing the fetch, you would then perform a diff between the branch you want to merge into and the branch that you fetched. Then you would checkout each individual file that has changed and commit them to your liking. I apologize if this process is tedious, but I don't know of any way to make the dialog pop up if any file changes during a merge.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  So, if do a fetch, how do I proceed to resolve the differences (manually) between the files?

Comment: No need to apologize for trying to help! :) So, what is CHECKOUT then? I'm currently a citizen of a version control country (MKS), where "check out" means to pull the file from the MKS repository (using GIT terminology) so I can modify it, and LOCKS THE FILE TO MY NAME. If someone else on my team tries to check out the file, they'll be told that the file is locked to me. Then, when I'm done, I check in the file, the changes are pushed (again using GIT lingo), and my lock is removed. So, does GIT checkout have anything in common with MKS checkout?  Thanks!

Comment: git does not lock files, so no, checkout in git does not have that in common with MKS. A checkout is mostly used to switch between branches, but it also allows for the ability to check out individual files (I personally only checkout individual files when I am resetting it back to a stable state.) Because git is a distributed VCS, there is no need to lock files. Each developer has a copy of the repository on his / her development machine. Pushing and pulling are used to share updated code. I think you are ultimately trying to accomplish something that git was not designed for. Hope that helps!

Comment: Jtiger - Belated thanks for the response. Per your last sentence, yes, that's an issue for us. We are used to being able to tell that a file is locked (per MKS version control). We have only two or three developers so we usually can live with waiting until the other programmer has checked in his code and if we can't, we work around it manually. Thanks again.